# Using PHP to send mails from my organisation's email id?

Tags: php, email, smtp

So, I developed this web application which needs me to send emails to everyone (details in a mysql database), providing a unique set of user credentials. I have a virtual server on the University network where I am hosting my PHP based application, so it obviously doesn't have its own mail server/SMTP settings.

So, if I were to send out mails from a university network, I guess I should request the network admin for the SMTP settings for the university mail network and then use PEAR for it right?

I need to confirm this because it's kind of a big deal to make a request like that, and I myself have never used PHP to send mails 'from' an external email id not linked to the server.

Are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: try using simple mail. See if that works

Comment: You might also want to contact your university's postmaster to let them know that you're going to be doing this - if your application suddenly starts sending out a lot of emails unexpectedly, they're quite likely to assume it's spamming and shut it down for you.

Comment: Simple mail doesn't work. And yes I will be making sure that it doesn't get flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [PEAR::mail](http://pear.php.net/Mail) to send mails via SMTP server. However, if SMTP is configured on localhost you can simply use mail() function to send mail. You can also connect to SMTP server via socket but then you need to handle whole protocol communication.

Comment: It isn't configured. I myself installed WAMP on the server. I understand that I can configure php.ini with the SMTP, but what exact details do I need to do that?